# Why do I have to push the changes I just pulled from origin in Git?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository on my local machine that I cloned from my remote server. The Git repository that I cloned from is a bare repository.

One thing that still puzzles me is that, when changes have been made on origin and I do `git pull origin master` to update my local repository, `git status` then tells me that I'm X commits ahead of origin, where X is the number of commits I just pulled.

This is despite the fact that the commit logs are already identical.

So I always do a `git push origin master` afterwards, but I was just wondering if anybody could explain why this is necessary and whether I might not be doing this incorrectly.

It seems to me that if I just pulled the changes from origin, the two repos should be identical. So why am I told that I'm ahead of origin then? Is this related to the fact that it's a bare repository?

Here's the situation in a bit more detail, for clarity's sake:

I have a bare git repo (hub) on a remote server. That repo has two clones: "dev" on my local machine and "staging", on the same server as origin.

When I make changes on dev, I then `git push origin master` them to the bare "hub" repo. Then I log on to the remote server, `cd` to the "staging" repo and do `git pull origin master` to update "staging" from "hub".

After I've done this, if I compare the hub and staging commit logs using `git log --pretty=oneline` I can see that they're identical.

However, if I do `git status` in the "staging" directory I get the following:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So then I usually do `git push origin master` from there, and I'm told:

```
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

Everything works properly, but I just have this nagging question in my mind whether I didn't make a mistake when setting the repos up, or whether this is normal...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`man git-pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html):

> Merge into the current branch the remote branch `next`:
>
> ```
> $ git pull origin next
> ```
>
> **This leaves a copy of `next` temporarily in `FETCH_HEAD`, but does not update any remote-tracking branches**. Using remote-tracking branches, the same can be done by invoking fetch and merge:
>
> ```
> $ git fetch origin
> $ git merge origin/next
> ```

Emphasis is mine.

Basically, Git is telling you that your updated master is ahead of `origin/master`, which is a [*remote tracking branch* for master](http://book.git-scm.com/4_tracking_branches.html). Since this tracking branch is not being updated by `git pull origin master` (as indicated in the man page), you *are* technically ahead of it. Calling `git fetch origin` updates your remote tracking branches and then you can merge that tracking branch in by hand (as indicated in the second manpage example).

AFAIK, if you do not specify a branch name with `git pull` (e.g. `git pull origin`), it will read `.git/config` for what it should fetch and the remote tracking branches *will* be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the summary. I'm still trying to get my head around the ins and outs of Git so this has helped clear things up a bit for me.

Comment: @mtnorthrop: I don't blame you for being confused by this. I know Git pretty well, and it still seems odd that it doesn't update the corresponding remote tracking branch when it does this.

Comment: I agree this can be counter-intuitive in most cases, but `git pull` allows you to pull from *any* branch into your current branch, so Git does not know which remote branch to update (if any). There is some additional explanation in [`man git-fetch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html), under the third "note" under the `<refspec>` description. I can also agree that Git can often be confusing! "With great power comes great complexity," or something like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you also made changes locally? If so, then your `git pull` retrieves the remote commits and generates a merge commit descending from your local `HEAD` and `origin`'s `HEAD`

Comment: No, that's the strange thing. I have to do this even when no changes have been made locally.