# Why do I have to "push" when I have reset my repo to the last commit?

Tags: git

I've been getting up to speed with Git (very pleased with it so far) but I'm still a little confused about a couple of things. I'm using SourceTree on a Mac.

In particular, my team and I had been making changes, committing them and then pushing to our remote bare repo living on my linux server. Separately, I had been doing some experiments on my laptop and ended up with some divergent local changes.

Rather than trying to merge them, I decided that I really wanted to just revert my laptop back to the state of the remote repo. I had tried pulling down changes from the remote repo and after being warned that I would need to merge, I decided to revert ("reset", I guess, in GIT language) to the last offical commit. I did this for everything and was then able to pull down the files.

However, SourceTree told me that there were 24 changes that I had to push back to the remote server but I couldn't see what those changes were (particularly since my goal was to not have anything I did be saved). That made me very nervous.

Ultimately, I just blew away the entire folder (including the .git) and just cloned the remote respository again.

The downside of that last is that if you have any untracked new files, they will just get deleted if you don't remember to copy them somewhere else temporarily.

My question is whether there is any way to just revert my local working copy (and the .git contents) to whatever is the latest state of the remote repo, leaving any untracked files in the working copy untouched?

I did find [Why do I have to push the changes I just pulled from origin in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283829/why-do-i-have-to-push-the-changes-i-just-pulled-from-origin-in-git) but it doesn't really answer either of the issues I describe here.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is  `git reset --hard origin/master`, assuming that `origin` is your remote and `master` is your branch.

**Warning**: this will blow away any modified files you have, but it should **not** affect untracked files.

Comment: `git reset --hard` does **not** affect untracked files. However it would cause any uncommitted changes to be lost completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git checkout` to reset individual working-tree files to how they look in the index (on HEAD or on any specific revision or branch).

Note that the meaning of *checkout* in git is vastly different from what it means in other SCM systems. It means "look at it", not "lock it for others until I check it in again".

Comment: Yeah, I had already discovered that "head", "checkout" and a few other things don't mean the same thing as in other SCMs. Frankly it just left me scratching my head as to why they felt they had to use the same terms when they meant something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough of the specifics of your git pull & git reset you performed to understand why git said there were 24 changes you had to push back.  It's probably too late to re-create the exact commands & errors that occurred, but we could probably decode what happened with that information.

If in the future, you have the same situation where your local changes have diverged from the remote repository, I'd recommend a slightly different git workflow.  First start with

`git fetch`

This will retrieve any new commits and update the origin/master remote branch along with any other remote branches, but unlike `git pull` it will not change any of your local branches, even master.

Now if you want to save your divergent local changes for future use, checkout a new topical branch,

`git checkout -b my_feature`

Now that you have a branch pointer on your divergent local work, you can reset your master branch pointer without worrying about losing your work.  First, change to your master branch (which should be at the same commit as my_feature)

`git checkout master`

And now reset that to the origin/master,

`git reset --hard origin/master`

Now your old work is saved off in `my_feature`, while your `master` branch once again matches the remote repository.

To save yourself this trouble in the future, I highly recommend always working on a topical branch.  That way you can `git pull` on master without worrying about your local work.  And when the time comes to share your work with the world, you can `rebase` your branch on to master before pushing, and no one else will even have to know about your local branch.

I'm a big fan of the Pro Git book, which is available online.   Here's their chapter about [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html).

Comment: This is incredibly helpful information, thank you for the detailed response. I have browsed through the Pro Git book which I pulled down as a PDF.